# Slicing Multidimensional Array by a variable

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, julia, slice

I am writing a method which accepts a two dimensional array of doubles and an int row number as parameters and returns the highest value of the elements in the given row.

it looks like this:

```
function getHighestInRow(A, i)
        return(maximum(A[:i,:]))
end
```

the issue i am having is when i slice the array with

```
A[:i,:]
```

I get an argument error because the `:i` makes `i` get treated differently.

the code works in the other direction with

```
A[:,i,:]
```

Is there a way to escape the colon? so that `i` gets treated as a variable after a colon?

Comment: For better performance it might be better to use a **view** or to code it up explicitly with a `for` loop

Comment: You think so? Worth testing in practice.

Comment: `A[i,:]` creates a new vector. Right? That's wasteful.

Comment: Sure but sometimes small views aren't fast either. Let me try it out.

Comment: You're right, the view is always faster. I can never work out what the actual rules are when slicing is faster, I thought that was for small arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing something strange with the colon. In this case you're using the symbol `:i` not the value of `i`. Just `getHighestInRow(A,i) = maximum(A[i,:])` should work.

Edit: As Dan Getz said in the comment on the question, `getHighestInRow(A,i) = maximum(@view A[i,:])` is more efficient, though, as the slicing will allocate a temporary unnecessary array.